# How can I add a redirect url for both iOS and Android for a Branch link?

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

If my app is not installed, I want to configure a branch deep link to redirect to the web url for my Testflight (iOS) or Android Beta (Android) builds.

Neither the Branch dashboard nor the API is allowing me to add both a web url for iOS and for android. If I do it for both, it removes the iOS url.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here -

You can configure web URLs for each of your Quick Links like this -
[image]

The behavior you observed that the iOS URL is removed might be due to a caching issue. This shouldn't cause any issue with the redirection. You can debug your link by appending "?debug=1" to it.